# Frequency resolution - resolution BW relation for different window functions

Tags: fft, frequency-spectrum

I am working on FFT based spectrum analyser and I am not sure how to proceed calculating the RBW.

According to the  [document](https://cdn.testequity.com/documents/pdf/Real-Time-Analysis-Fundamentals.pdf)  (page 20) in the link, RBW described as $k \frac{f_s}N$ where $f_s$ sampling frequency, $N$ FFT size and $k$ is window coefficent.

Since $\frac{f_s}N$ is simply frequency resolution, is there a way to calculate $k$ coefficent for different window functions?

I tried to check the book in the references but I couldn't find the information.